# how to get Toggle or switch selected item value to string?

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I am using this library to implment toogle button https://github.com/GwonHyeok/StickySwitch

How can I get Switch item as male or female value to string ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCV3e.png)

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private EditText textview;
        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Set Selected Change Listener
            StickySwitch stickySwitch = (StickySwitch) findViewById(R.id.sticky_switch);
            stickySwitch.setOnSelectedChangeListener(new StickySwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedChange(@NotNull StickySwitch.Direction direction) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Now Selected : " + direction.name());





                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="#fff"
    tools:context="io.ghyeok.stickyswitchdemo.MainActivity">

    <io.ghyeok.stickyswitch.widget.StickySwitch
        android:id="@+id/sticky_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:iconPadding="18dp"
        app:iconSize="22dp"
        app:leftIcon="@drawable/male"
        app:leftText="Male"
        app:rightIcon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        app:rightText="Female"
        app:selectedTextSize="14sp"
        app:sliderBackgroundColor="@color/colorSliderBackground"
        app:switchColor="@color/colorSwitchColor"
        app:textColor="@color/colorTextColor"
        app:textSize="12sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `direction.name()` is what you want. See your logs : `Log.d(TAG, "Now Selected : " + direction.name());`

Comment: This will give me LEFT & right . I want to store Male or female in string

Comment: then do `String value; if(direction.name().equals("LEFT")) { value = "Male"; } else {value = "Female";}`

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you for comment . Could you please tell me How to pass this value on click button to go next activity?

Comment: on Button click check `stickySwitch.getDirection()`

Comment: @VladMatvienko when i used this  
String gender= String.valueOf(stickySwitch.getDirection());
again it stores LEFT or RIGHT in gender.
while i want to store male or female .

Comment: why don't you check if direction is left, then it's male, else - female? Isn't it obvious???

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it's helpful

```
String.valueOf(direction.name());
```

Comment: This will give me LEFT & right . I want to store Male or female in string .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ToggleButton then you have methods:

```
getTextOff() which will get you the text value for when the button is off
getTextOn()  which will get you the text value for when the button is on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stickySwitch.setOnSelectedChangeListener(new StickySwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedChange(@NotNull StickySwitch.Direction direction) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Now Selected : " + direction == StickySwitch.Direction.LEFT ? 
                "Male" : "Female");
    }
```

Comment: Error:(34, 74) error: cannot find symbol variable Direction

Comment: @User_FIt `StickySwitch.Direction`

Answer (score 0):

```
                        String gender;
                        if (stickySwitch.getDirection().equals(LEFT)) {
                                gender = "Male";
                        } else {
                                gender = "Female";
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "gender112: " +stickySwitch.getDirection() );
```

Answer (score 0):

StickySwitch library updated to 0.0.6

that version is support get or set text programmatically.

so if you want to get current status text

**java :**

```
stickySwitch.getText();
```

More info : [Sticky Switch - Set, Get Text Programmatically](https://github.com/GwonHyeok/StickySwitch#set-get-text-programmatically)